# Flex (AIR) setup print time

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

How can i set print time for flex printjob.

when the time is ripe my program will automatically print my job

eg. i want to print my job at 11.00 AM i will set print time in my program to 11.00 AM when time is 11.00 AM flex will automatically print my job

Comment: "When the time is ripe"? What does that mean?

Comment: eg. i want to print my job at 11.00 AM i will set print time in my program to 11.00 AM when time is 11.00 AM flex will automatically print my job

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Flex is the wrong tool for this.

You could use a timer to trigger something at 11am, however unless the application is active the timer gets wiggy as the frame rates of the app will slow down.  This is one of the changes made in the recent version of the player to help w/ battery life and performance on mobile devices.  so, there is no guarantee the timer will trigger at the correct time.

Additionally, Flex is a client side tool.  There is no guarantee that your users will have their Flex client up and running and active when 11am rolls around.  Depending on your user base, there is also no guarantee that your 11am is there 11am.

All that said, the best you can do from Flex is to pop up a print window which will require user interaction.  I wouldn't consider that automatic.

If you want to do this server side, use your server side language, or some server side daemon to trigger the print job at 11am.  If you want to do this on your clients, there should be a way to schedule this with the OS, or to write a java or .NET program to run in the background and print when appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I develope desktop application (adobe air). I don't have server side.

Comment: Flex is still the wrong tool for this and everything I said still applies. You may be able to create a "Terminate and Stay Resident" program which you distribute w/ your AIR app and execute using NativeProcess.  Unless you have very specific user configuration, this is going to be ripe for errors.  What type of printer does the user print to?